# Laravel Blade: concatenating variables as string inside old() function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to implement the `old()` on a bunch of checkboxes generated by 2 foreach (one with key `$day_key` and one with `$period_key`)

```
<input type="checkbox" 
  name="availability[{{ $day_key }}][{{ $period_key }}]" 
  {{ ( old('availability["'.$day_key.'"]["'.$period_key.'"]') == 'on' ) ? 'checked' : '' }} />
```

I need to print this string inside the old() function:

```
'availability["'.$day_key.'"]["'.$period_key.'"]'
```

but it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
{{ old('availability')[$day_key][$period_key] === 'on' ? 'checked' : '' }}
```

Comment: @FredK what exactly doesn't work? You're getting an error or something?

Comment: Error says: `Undefined index: monday (View: /www/project/resources/views/users/create_edit.blade.php)` where `monday` is first key of $days array. `$days = array('monday' => 'Monday', 'tuesday' => 'Tuesday', ... )`

Comment: @FredK well, it's not related to the original issue. You need to make sure you're using correct keys and maybe even check if a value with given key exists in the array `isset(old('availability')[$day_key][$period_key] ) && old('availability')[$day_key][$period_key] === 'on' ? 'checked' : ''`

Comment: Yes, using the code in your previous comment it works, though I don't understand why! You just added an `isset` check. Without it, it doesn't work. Could you help me understand why? Thanks

Comment: @FredK `isset()` just checks if a value exists in the array in flashed session.

Comment: Hi Alexey, your solution has a problem yet: the old() works when check a checkbox but when I *un*check a checked checkbox it keeps checked.